# Downloading content from CONTENTFUL api using Python

Tags: python-2.7, contentful

I'm trying to download a videofile from contentful. After getting asset id how can i proceed to download the content from CONTENTFUL using that asset  id ?

Edit: I am not asking for exact code. Just need the steps to proceed. Or any link. The docs confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is you use the asset id to fetch the asset from Contentful. The asset then contains the actual url to your binary video file.

Like this:

```
client.asset('<asset_id>').url()
```